# Capture image from oscilloscope and store on PC using LabVIEW

Tags: labview, remote-control

I am trying to remotely control an oscilloscope from Agilent (DSO-X 3034A) using LabVIEW. I want to take a screen capture and store it on the computer. I tried the following:

The commands inside the string are:

```
:SAVE:FILename "temp.png";:SAVE:IMAGe:FACTors ON;:SAVE:IMAGe:FORMat PNG;:SAVE:IMAGe:INKSaver OFF;:SAVE:IMAGe:STARt;
```

I get the following errors:

Thank you

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ EDIT ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I managed to save the image on the oscilloscope. I am currently trying to move it and save it on the computer instead. I tried the following:
[image: Screen capture]

However after writing the "HARDcopy" commands I get the following error:
[image: Errors]

Answer (score 0):

1. Your header is undefined. Refer to the "Serial Communications" documentation in order to see what the instrument is expecting in the header. You should right click your string constant and do "\ Codes Display" so that if the documentation calls for a `\n` character, you're not accidentally sending a `\` character followed by an `n` character.
2. Query Unterminated means you're not terminating the query as the instrument expects. It looks like you have a newline, but assuming you're using windows, it's possible that the instrument doesn't want the extra `\r` that is there by default. Again, you'll have to refer to the documentation to be sure.